# Incorrect versions of files in downloadable GitHub zip

Tags: git, github, version-control, installation

I am creating an installer for my application that relies on downloading my GitHub repository as a zip file. However, I noticed that GitHub is not packaging the correct version of several files into the zip. When I download [this file](https://github.com/joelamos/SourceRadio/blob/master/audio/controller/CSCore.dll) from the file tree, I get the correct version (506 KB). However, when I [download the repository](https://github.com/joelamos/SourceRadio/archive/master.zip), the file has a different size (514 KB).

This issue is causing my installation to fail. What should I do?

Comment: IDK why that's happening ([caching maybe?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)), but it's generally considered bad practice to store compiled binaries in with the source version control. Perhaps you should consider using the releases feature.

Comment: I'm aware that it is bad practice, but I've weighed the tradeoffs and decided to go this route. Binaries or not, the most recent files should be included in the zip. I'm trying to keep my installer as small as possible, which is why I've not used releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in my `.gitattributes` file, I had the line `* eol=crlf`. This was marking all my files as text files and changing their line endings, which was corrupting my binary files.

To fix the problem, I excluded my binary files from being marked as text files by adding the following lines to my `.gitattributes` file.

```
*.dll -text
*.exe -text
```

I then removed and re-added the affected binary files.

Thanks to GitHub support for helping me to figure this out!